# How to create stack of divs and display on scroll dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is a link to my website template which i am designing i want the next div to be appeared smoothly but when i scroll fast it shows borders of div!!
This is a (http://jsfiddle.net/kailash8591/329cos9y/embedded/result/)
Here is the reference site i am trying to follow design!!
    [chameleon](http://themeforest.net/item/chameleon-android-app-promo-site-muse-template/full_screen_preview/6892619)
How can i achieve this using jQuery?

```
$(function () {

    $(".wrapper").scroll(function () {

        var height = $(".active").height();

        if ($(".wrapper").scrollTop() > (height - 400)) {
            //alert("wrapper content "+$(".wrapper content").scrollTop());
            //ert("height of wrapper"+height);
            $(".active").animate({
                'opacity': 0
            }, 'slow');

            $next = $(".active").next();
            $next.addClass('active');
            $next.siblings().removeClass('active')
            $prev = $next.prev();
            $next.animate({
                'opacity': 1
            }, 'slow');
        }

    });

});
```

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="companylogo">logo</div>
    <div class="companytitle">Click Online Services</div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper" id='wrapper'>
    <!--column-->
    <div class="green active" id="green">
        <img class="bg-img" src="http://s15.postimg.org/n4xk7g62j/green.jpg">
        <div class='Description'>
            <p> <span>Company Brief</span> 3 click online services is a leading Solutions Provider, implementing technology and design to deliver the best in time. Founded with an aim to revamp end user's perception of the Web. Industry and still growing, 3 click online services have added a whole new dimension to Web Development and Design. 3 click online services is not just limited his boundaries to Web development but also Software Development Logo Designing etc. 3 click online services are a bunch of passionate people working round the clock to bring that 'smile-of-content' on your face. We stay a step ahead of your expectations, upholding high and professional standards of work. With our technical expertise at play, all our solutions are tailor-made to suite your business needs. Our core team of developers, programmers and artists are dedicated to offering business class services with a touch of compassion. Talking about clients, our relationships do not end with deployment.</p>
            <p>Companies Services Logo Designing 3 click online services provide an artistic creation of logos. Web Designing and Development 3 click online services solution provides a broad range of web design services from static html websites to web applications and software development. We focus on achieving our clients' business goals. We know that a successful website is not only about a beautiful design - it is about understanding the clients' business requirements and translating them into scalable web design solutions. We are proud to be a part of our clients' team, unlike many other web companies who merely treat designing as a job. The end result is websites and web applications that are consistent with our clients' online expectations we pay high attention to details, provide fast turn-around and are extremely affordable. Our clients range from individuals to large corporations throughout the world. All of the cutting-edge market tendencies are presented in Development Services of our company. We are skilled in Html, Java, .NET, PHP .Our web sites and networks have a wide functionality and are integrated with payment systems, mobile platforms and corporate resources. We are passionate about what we do, and believe that the best way to demonstrate our expertise is to show you our work.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="red">
        <img class="bg-img" src="http://s15.postimg.org/hi179z3jv/red.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="yellow">
        <img class="bg-img" src="http://s15.postimg.org/c966c3l4r/yellow.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="blue" id="blue">
        <img class="bg-img" src="http://s15.postimg.org/wmxb7hrqz/blue.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="dblue">
        <img class="bg-img" src="http://s15.postimg.org/dj3zr5ewr/darkblue.jpg">
    </div>
    <!--contentwrapper-->
</div>
```

```
 html, body {
     height: 100%;
     margin:0;
     padding:0;
     overflow: hidden;
     font-family:'robotolight';
 }
 .wrapper {
     position: relative;
     overflow-y: scroll;
     width: 100%;
     overflow-x: hidden;
 }
 .wrapper {
     position:relative;
     margin-top:65px;
     background-image: url("http://s15.postimg.org/3vvw3owjf/black.jpg");
 }
 .bg-img {
     width:1366px;
     height:2000px;
 }
 .wrapper, .green {
     height:100%;
     left:0;
     top:0;
     opacity:1;
 }
 .red, .blue, .yellow, .dblue {
     opacity:0;
     position:absolute;
     left:0;
     top:0;
     height:100%;
     border-style: none;
     border-color: transparent;
     background-color: transparent;
     /*     display:none; */
 }
 .green {
     border-style: none;
     position:absolute;
     left:0;
     top:0;
     background-color: transparent;
     border-color: transparent;
     z-index: 2;
 }
 .green img {
     width:1366px;
     height:1366px;
     margin-top:-388px;
 }
 .red img {
     margin-top: -208px
 }
 .yellow img {
     margin-top: -388px;
 }
 .blue img {
     margin-top: -388px;
 }
 .dblue img {
     margin-top: -388px;
 }
 .red {
     z-index:4;
 }
 .yellow {
     z-index: 6;
 }
 .blue {
     z-index: 10;
 }
 .dblue {
     z-index: 12;
 }
 .header {
     height:60px;
     width:100%;
     z-index:200;
     position:fixed;
     background-color:rgba(2, 2, 2, 0.8);
     color:white;
     font-size: 24px;
     text-align: center;
     padding-top: 5px
 }
 .header .companylogo {
     position: absolute;
     width:137px;
     height:40px;
     float:left;
     margin: 6px 8px;
     overflow:hidden;
     border-color: white;
     border:1px solid;
 }
 .header .companytitle {
     width: 280px;
     margin: auto;
     padding-top: 12px;
 }
 .Description {
     position:absolute;
     top: 34px;
     left:200px;
     margin: auto;
     width: 700px;
     height: 400px;
     background-color: transparent;
     z-index: 51;
 }
```

Comment: You are still *trying* on that issue, you only set one `if` statement, your code is not clean, cache your elements, use `var` while introducing new variables... Too many things to point out in one single answer, and probably more sub-questions to come.

Comment: My best suggestion is to fully search SO for similar questions cause there's already plenty of answers on that topic, even with great examples and ideas.

Comment: Also why you use `.wrapper` instead of simply scrolling the `html, body` ? You have double scrollbars and looot of things to fix in your CSS.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

To be honest, if I were you I wouldn't bother with the pain of building a one page template from scratch. If this is for your company's website, look into working with pre-made templates, they're usually around 10 dollars, and they're worth it given the time they save you. (all you have to do is fill the website up, do some tweaking with the css and js, and maybe add some custom sections)

Anyway, this is just a suggestion, because I just briefly scrolled over chameleon, and you're going to encounter a lot of problems :)

Comment: zsawaf, this would be better as a comment as it does not directly answer the question

Comment: @TobyAllen I can't comment. I don't have the reputation for it. I was just trying to help the guy, but if you're going to down vote me, that's cool too.

Answer (score 0):

**[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/vufiz/3/edit)**

I would do it simply as:

- Store a desired color inside an element `data-*` attribute: `<div class="page" data-bgcolor="#27AE61">`. That color will be than assigned using JS to the `body` element.
- Create an Array that will dynamically collect all the elements positions and the colors resulting as: `[[0,"#27AE61"],[1250,"gold"],....etc]`
- On scroll get the Array item that matches the scroll position and retrieve it's color (when the element is mostly visible so I used `/1.5`)
- Set that color to `$('body')` and achieve the BODY bg color transition with CSS3: `body{ transition: background 3s;}`

JS/jQ:

```
var $page = $('.page'),
    pos2Color = [], // [[pos,color],[pos,color],...]
    winH, scrH, oldColor,
    start = true;

function getPosColorData(){ // Creates the Array [[pos, color], ... ]
   pos2Color = [];
   winH = $(window).height();
   scrH = $('html, body')[0].scrollHeight;
   $page.each(function(){
      pos2Color.push([
        this.getBoundingClientRect().top,
        this.dataset.bgcolor
      ]);
   });
}

$(window).on("scroll", function(){
  if(start){      // Do it only once on first scroll
    getPosColorData();
    start=false;
  }
  var st = $(this).scrollTop();
  var color = pos2Color.filter(function(k){ // Search in our Array...
    return  k[0] > ( st-winH / 1.5 );       // (change 1.5 to your needs)
  })[0][1];                                 // ...and retrieve the color!

  if(color!==oldColor){                     // Only if it's a new color!
    $("body").css({background: color});
    oldColor = color;
  }
}).on('resize', function(){
   start = true;  // Something changed, allow another take.
});
```

HTML:

```
  <header>
    <h1>HELLO WORLD</h1>
  </header>

  <div class="page" data-bgcolor="#27AE61"><h1>page1</h1></div>
  <div class="page" data-bgcolor="gold"><h1>page2</h1></div>
  <div class="page" data-bgcolor="#37e"><h1>page3</h1></div>
  <div class="page" data-bgcolor="#e73"><h1>page4</h1></div>
  <div class="page" data-bgcolor="#7fe"><h1>page5</h1></div>
```